# why my promise all function returns anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have two promises making an api call , both should return an array of data , I've tested the api locally with Postman , it works fine , but executing those two promises with Promise All it display on my console :

> Array [   [Function anonymous],   [Function anonymous], ]

would you please help to find where am I making the error ?

here is my code :

```
const allPromises = async () => {
    return await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
        .then((a) => console.log(a))
        .catch((e) => e);
};

const promise1 = useCallback(async () => {

    return userFollowers(link)
        .then((datax) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_FOLLOWING',
                payload: datax,
            });
            return Promise.resolve(datax);
        })
        .catch((e) => e);
}, [item]);

const promise2 = useCallback(async () => {
    return userFollowing(link2)
        .then((datax) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_FOLLOWERS',
                payload: datax,
            });
            return Promise.resolve(datax);
        })
        .catch((e) => e);
}, [item]);
```

Comment: You're having problems because you're mixing the new-style `await` with the old-style `.then().catch()` - only use _one-or-the-other_, not both.

Comment: there is no problem with mixing `await` and `then`. Additionally, `then` is by no means replaced by `await`

Comment: I removed await from promise all the error remains there

Comment: The mix of syntax is irrelevant, this code is behaving exactly as expected. `promise1` should be `promise1()` to actually get a promise for `all` to resolve.

Comment: Irrelevant to the error, but `return await promise` from an `async` function is unnecessary; just `return promise`, the `async` function will behave correctly (i.e. an `async` function will create a promise for a non-promise return value, but will return a promise directly).

Comment: Never do `.catch((e) => e);`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`promise1` and `promise2` *aren't* promises. They are async functions that return promises, so you need to call them

```js
const allPromises = async () => {
    return await Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()])
        .then((a) => console.log(a))
        .catch((e) => e);
};
```